# Could some one explain me how this program is having effeciency of N2LogN ? I think It must be N2

Tags: python, time, big-o

```
class Solution(object):
    def mincostToHireWorkers(self, quality, wage, K):
        from fractions import Fraction
        ans = float('inf')

        N = len(quality)
        for captain in xrange(N):
            # Must pay at least wage[captain] / quality[captain] per qual
            factor = Fraction(wage[captain], quality[captain])
            prices = []
            for worker in xrange(N):
                price = factor * quality[worker]
                if price < wage[worker]: continue
                prices.append(price)

            if len(prices) < K: continue
            prices.sort()
            ans = min(ans, sum(prices[:K]))

        return float(ans)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.
According to me, 
O(n)=N(N+logN)=N2+NLogN>> = N2
N for outer loop
N for inner loop
logN for sorting

[link to the program](https://leetcode.com/articles/minimum-cost-to-hire-k-workers/#)

Answer (score 3):

> Correct me if I'm wrong. According to me, O(n)=N(N+logN)=N2+NLogN>> = N2 N for outer loop N for inner loop logN for sorting

The mistake is the last part. Sorting takes `N log N` time, not `log N`.

And if you think about it, how could sorting possibly take less than linear time? You obviously have to check each value at least once, right?

So, the total time is `N (N + N log N)`, which is `O(N^2 log N)`.

Comment: @abarnert , bad memory.! Thanks